# Customising fields in ModelResource for downloading data

Tags: django, django-import-export

Using the Django [Import/Export library](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org), I'm currently using the following code to create a `resource` that can be used to download data from a Django project in multiple formats (e.g. csv, excel, json etc):

`from import_export import resources`

```
class Resource1(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('First_Name', 'Last_Name')

resource = Resource1()
dataset = resource.export(queryset)
```

I am now creating a number of versions of the resource with different properties (e.g. different fields).  Is it possible to alter Meta (or _meta) dynamically so that it is created with the properties that are needed?

```
class Resource2(resources.ModelResource):
    def __init__(self, fields):
        self.Meta.fields = fields
        # self._meta.fields = fields
    class Meta:
        model = Person

resource = Resource2(['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Address'])
dataset = resource.export(queryset)
```

When I try this, the resulting download is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a straight-forward way to dynamically change the fields that are within the inner `class Meta` section of an instance of the class. The `create_resource` function below creates a customized version of the class on demand and then returns an instance:

```
def create_resource(django_model, model_fields):
    class model_resource(resources.ModelResource):
        class Meta:
           model = django_model
           fields = model_fields
    return model_resource()

resource = create_resource(Person, ['First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Address'])
```

I can then use the resource to export data:

```
dataset = resource.export(queryset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your question correctly, but I don't think that you can make the Meta options 'dynamic'.

However, what you could do is to have an abstract base class (Resource1) and inherit from it for e.g. Resource2? Here's a link to the django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: I don't think it will help - I need the user to be able to change which fields are included at run time